# i dont want to stock it in binary so i didnt set it to "wb" what should i do?

Tags: python

```
import pickle

    class player :
        def __init__(self, name , level ):
            self.name = name
            self.level = level
        def itiz(self):
            print("ur name is {} and ur lvl{}".format(self.name,self.level))
    
    p = player("bob",12)
    with open("Player.txt","w") as fichier :
        record = pickle.Pickler(fichier)
        record.dump(p)
```

this is the error write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Is it just a case of binary or do you want it to be human readable? Do you have a preference of encodings?

Comment: I believe pickling requires binary.  If you want to save as plain text, you might use json instead.

Comment: What you "want" is immaterial. If a data structure is binary (as in the case of `pickle`) you will have to store it as such.

Comment: @Selcuk - It is highly material. Many protocols convert from binary to some sort of ascii representation.

Comment: @tdelaney Care to elaborate? What protocols would automagically convert when you open the file in ASCII mode for writing?

Comment: @Selcuk - Many protocols restrict data to ascii - or these days utf-8. Http for example. And its common to store data in an ascii encoded manner. Certificates or key files for example. You can also layer other encodings such as UTF-16 on top of that. I don't know why OP doesn't want to write binary, but character encoding binary data is normal.

Comment: @tdelaney Ah, you meant a secondary text based protocol to wrap the original binary representation. That's fair although I doubt that's what the OP wants. It will technically be text but won't make the data human readable as in JSON or XML.

Comment: @Selcuk - You mean like `jsonpickle`? I don't know of an auto-encoder for XML but double encoding with the standard library is pretty easy.

Comment: @Selcuk - Unfortunately, OP has remained quiet so we really don't know what the intention is.

Answer (score 1):

Its common to convert binary to ascii and there are several different commonly used protocols to do it. This example does a base64 encoding. Hex encoding is another popular choice. Whoever consumes this file will need to know its encoding. But it also needs to know its a python pickle, so not much extra labor there.

```
import pickle
import binascii

class player :
    def __init__(self, name , level ):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
    def itiz(self):
        print("ur name is {} and ur lvl{}".format(self.name,self.level))

p = player("bob",12)
with open("Player.txt","w") as fichierx:
    fichierx.write(binascii.b2a_base64(pickle.dumps(p)).decode('ascii'))

print(open("Player.txt").read())
```

Comment: This is quite nice!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to follow all of the chat in the comments, and none of it makes much sense to me.  You don't want to "stock it in binary", but Pickle is a binary format, so by choosing Pickle as your serialization method, that decision has already been made. Your easy answer is therefore just what you say in your subject line...use 'wb' instead of 'w', and move on (remembering to use 'rb' when you read your file back in):

```
p = player("bob",12)
with open("Player.pic", "wb") as fichierx:
    pickle.dump( p, fichierx )
```

If you really want to use a text-based format...something human readable, that wouldn't be difficult given the data I see in your object.  Just store your fields in a dict, add `load` and `store` methods to your object, and use the `json` library to implement those methods by reading and writing your dict from/to disk in JSON format.

There is one valid reason I know of to add an "ascification" layer around your pickled data, and that's if you want to be able to copy/paste it around, like you commonly do with SSH keys, certs, etc. As someone else said, this doesn't make your data more human readable...just easier to move around, like in email and such.  If this is what you want, although you didn't say so, then all of the stuff above comes back on the table, I do admit.  In that case, please take all of my blabbering to mean "tell us what your requirements really are".

Answer (score 0):

Just in case JSON is an option you'd consider, here's an implementation of that:

```
import json

class Player(dict):
    def __init__(self, name, level, **args):

        super(Player, self).__init__()

        # This magic line lets you access a Player's data as attributes of the object, but have
        # them be stored in a dictionary (this object's alter ego).  It is possible to do this with an
        # explicit dict attribute for storage if you don't like subclassing 'dict' to do this.
        self.__dict__ = self

        # Normal initialization (but using attribute syntax!)
        self.name = name
        self.level = level

        # Allow for on-the-fly attributes
        for k,v in args.items():
            self[k] = v

    def itiz(self):
        print("ur name is {} and ur lvl{}".format(self.name, self.level))

    def dump(self, fpath):
        with open(fpath, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self, f)

    @staticmethod
    def load(fpath):
        with open(fpath) as f:
            return Player(**json.load(f))


p = Player("bob", 12)
print("This iz " + p.name)
p.occupation = 'Ice Cream Man'
p.itiz()
p.dump('/tmp/bob.json')

p2 = Player.load('/tmp/bob.json')
p2.itiz()
print(p.name + "is a " + p.occupation)
```

Result:

```
This iz bob
ur name is bob and ur lvl12
ur name is bob and ur lvl12
bob is a Ice Cream Man
```

Note that this implementation acts just as if the 'dict' wasn't there.  The constructor takes individual starting values, and additional attributes can be set on the object at will, and they are saved off and restored too.

Serialization:

```
{"name": "bob", "level": 12, "occupation": "Ice Cream Man"}
```